# Call to a member function num_rows() on array in codeigniter query

Tags: codeigniter

```
$this->db->select("sub_courses as courses");
$this->db->from("second_sub_courses");
if(!empty($params['searchTerm']))
{
    $this->db->like('courses', $params['searchTerm']);
}
$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
$this->db->select("course_name as courses");
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->from("all_courses");
if(!empty($params['searchTerm']))
{
    $this->db->like('courses', $params['searchTerm']);
}
$query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 
$query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2)->result();
$result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
return $result;
```

I am creating an autocomplete box which not working yet due to this query. Here, I am using a union to get two table data in a single column using `courses` key attribute but now it throws an error as I mentioned in my question I don't have any idea about this error. How can I fix this error? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Remove `->result()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `->result()`, please check below code.

```
$this->db->select("sub_courses as courses");
    $this->db->from("second_sub_courses");
    if(!empty($params['searchTerm']))
    {
        $this->db->like('courses', $params['searchTerm']);
    }
    $query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    $this->db->select("course_name as courses");
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->from("all_courses");
    if(!empty($params['searchTerm']))
    {
        $this->db->like('courses', $params['searchTerm']);
    }
    $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 
    $query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);
    $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
    return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `->result()`

```
$query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);
```